# Should I rely on Google Translate?

Tags: web, language, localization, google, chrome

The majority of my users access my website with Google Chrome. Google Chrome has Google Translate built-in, which lets you translate webpages. Instead of manually creating separate website locales for every language, is it OK to rely on Google Translate to do the job?

Comment: What is "the majority"? Are you willing to let 49% have no translation? (Or 20% or even 2%?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find out. Here's a paragraph from French Wikipedia:

> Wikipédia est un projet d’encyclopédie collective établie sur Internet, universelle, multilingue et fonctionnant sur le principe du wiki. Wikipédia a pour objectif d’offrir un contenu librement réutilisable, objectif et vérifiable, que chacun peut modifier et améliorer.

Here's Google's translation into English:

> Wikipedia is a project of collective encyclopaedia established on the internet, universal, multilingual and running on the wiki principle. Wikipedia aims to provide free reusable content, objective and verifiable, that anyone can modify and improve.

It's not bad. But is it good enough?

(I'd rather have my website's copy be better than than.)